# How to make a bat chart?

Tags: graphs

I'm looking for a way to make a bat chart. For clarity, I mean something like [this](http://bacliffexplorationsociety.org/wiki/index.php?title=Bat_chart) (the picture on the bottom). I've seen quite a few of them ([one](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EFjbPMfVAAAU1fJ.jpg), [other](https://www.alternatehistory.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=timelines:artemis_conops.png) and [yet another](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0094576517309736-gr1.jpg)), and even more in aerospace articles.

Apparently, this is a NASA thing, but quite common in the community it seems. Nonetheless, I couldn't find a single software/library to make one of these. One could wonder if such thing exists, but given the amount I've seen (and all with roughly the same layout) I'd suspect there must be something.

I've tried to look for anything related, but these bits of information was the best I could find. It really doesn't help that most search queries try to correct me, and show results for bar charts instead...

**Edit**
The software should run on Windows 7. As for price, don't mind it. Even if I find a certain software too expensive, just having a reference might point to an equivalent freeware (e.g. like Open Office is to Microsoft Word).

Comment: I suspect they use simple Powerpoint or similar slideshow editors.

Comment: "`show results for bar charts instead`" - just surround the search term with double quotes :   `"bat chart"`, not `bat chart`

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I found most search engines seem to ignore quotes today, so add to that: check with different engines. DDG seems to honor them in a way, MetaGer definitely does. Others? Rather so-so. // **Jak:** as we recommend software here (not "ways"), could you specify on which OS it should run and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions?

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for pointing it out. I've added the info to the question.

Comment: Google certainly honours double quotes

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica does it? I've long stopped using it (got too annoying with its popups, and I try to limit my connections to their data collection as much as possible). Last time I checked they did not. Or only occasionally. No clear pattern.

Comment: Same here, but it does (would I say so, if it did not? ;-). Like you, I [prefer to be Google free](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187982/how-can-i-escape-google), but I can still remember when they were the only game in town (heck, I can still remember when [HotBot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotBot) was the only search engine worth using). Last time I used Google, they used a plus sign to indicate "must have". I.e `+bat chart`, but they seem to have moved moved on. OP can use Google or try double quotes on other search engines, as he pleases. I hope you had a "good slide" ;-)